# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'slcount' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

iam trying to iterate through the results obtained from the database,
in the if condition am checking for the condition and if it is true then i want to increment the value

```
for row in rows:
  if row.LeavesApplied.type_id == "SICK_LEAVE" and row.Employee.leave_eligibility_id == 2:
    global slcount
    slcount+= 1
  elif row.LeavesApplied.type_id == "CASUAL_LEAVE" and row.Employee.leave_eligibility_id == 2:
    clcount += 1
  elif row.LeavesApplied.type_id == "PRIVILEGED_LEAVE" and row.Employee.leave_eligibility_id == 2:
    plcount += 1
```

but am getting an error saying

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'slcount' referenced before assignment
```

I also tried by giving "global" but it is showing the below error.

```
NameError: global name 'slcount' is not defined
```

Comment: If you tried `global`, what happened? That's what *should* have solved the problem.

Comment: @nneonneo Only if the variable actually exists in the global namespace.

Comment: by the way, global is a anti-pattern, use returnvalues instead.

Comment: @Daniel The OP probably doesn't want and need `global` nevertheless. Instead, setting the count variables to 0 seems to be appropriate, as given in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't assignment a value to `plcount` before using it.

```
slcount = clcount = plcount = 0
for row in rows:
    ...
```

**A little bit more:**

> Python is dynamically typed language

this means that you can do this in Python:

```
> foo = 12
> foo = 'aaa'
```

you see? I can assign any type of values to a variable. Instead of in a static typed language:

```
> int foo;
> foo = 12;
> foo = 'aaa'; // you can't do this!
```

However, this doesn't mean you can do this in Python:

```
> foo = foo + 1 # you haven't assign a value to foo!
```